# Nested Group Owner - LDAP Query

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server, ldap-query, adgroup

let's assume I have the user

`CN=testuser1,OU=Users,DC=corp,DC=com`

and I want to receive all groups where the user is registered as the owner. I am currently using the following filter:

`(|(ManagedBy=CN=testuser1,OU=Users,DC=corp,DC=com)(msExchCoManagedByLink=CN=testuser1,OU=Users,DC=corp,DC=com))`

However, it can happen that security groups are also entered as owners. How can I adjust the filter so that I can still find the right groups, even if the user is indirectly entered as the owner via a security group? Can this possibly be done with the matching rule OID `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941` **(LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN)**?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As [ManagedBy](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ManagedBy) is a dn Syntax and has a LinkID of 72, an even value implying that it is a [forward link](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Forward%20link), then you should be able to use something similar to: (or in combination with others)

```
(ManagedBy:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=N=testuser1,OU=Users,DC=corp,DC=com)
```

I have not tried this filter and there are limitations as to the depth of links that will be traversed in larger implementations.